# is it proper to initialize an instance variable in a constructor before preconditions in java

Tags: java

```
      `public Provider(String healthProvider) {
      if (this.healthProvider == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(PROVIDER_NULL);
      }
    
      if (this.healthProvider.isBlank()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(PROVIDER_ISBLANK);
      }
      this.healthProvider = healthProvider;
       this.patients = new ArrayList<Patient>();
  }
```

`

```
   when placed like this, my preconditions for isBlank does pass but that of null passes

      public Provider(String healthProvider) {
      this.healthProvider = healthProvider;
          this.patients = new ArrayList<Patient>();
      if (this.healthProvider == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(PROVIDER_NULL);
      }
    
      if (this.healthProvider.isBlank()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(PROVIDER_ISBLANK);
          }
    
   }
```

when i place the code like this my junit test passes but when i place the initialized data members after the preconditions, it doesnt pass.

Comment: Your first code makes no sense, since it is testing variables before setting those variables.

Answer (score 1):

Either would be fine, but your first should test the passed in `healthProvider` (since `this.healthProvider` isn't initialized yet, and when it is; it is using the passed `healthProvider`). Like,

```
public Provider(String healthProvider) {
    if (healthProvider == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(PROVIDER_NULL);
    } 
    if (healthProvider.isBlank()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(PROVIDER_ISBLANK);
    }
    this.healthProvider = healthProvider;
    this.patients = new ArrayList<Patient>();
}
```